# What is the best practice when hosting more then one tomcat based web application

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I do understand that using the same tomcat instance for a number of web applications has some risks (e.g. if one web application crashes tomcat it will terminate the other web applications as well.). The benefit is of course cost effectiveness since one server is enough and having all the web applications in one place makes it very easy to administrate.

Are there any industry guidelines on how a good setup with multiple web applications on tomcat should look like?

Answer (score 1):

## Pros

- One JVM to monitor
- Common libraries can be shared (sometimes risky)

## Cons

- Common HTTP thread pool all applications are using (you can, however, configure several connectors with different thread pools)
- One malfunctioning application can take down the whole server
- Restarting one application requires restarting all of them (if not using hot-deployment)

Comment: What level of separation between the web applications is needed to avoid the last point in the cons (the restarting issue)? Do I need two tomcats? Two hosts? Two engines..?

Comment: Most application servers are able to use separate class loaders per application. This is the best level of separation within single process of app. server.

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson: what I meant was: if you host 5 WAR files on Tomcat and you want to upgrade one of them (by replacing the WAR file) you must take down Tomcat, hence all 5 applications are down for a moment.

Comment: @Thomas Exactly. I have a server where I do just as you describe and I was wondering if that is really neccesary (to restart the entire server just to reload one web application). I know that the manager interface can be used to restart just one application but can this be done with command line executions?

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson: all you need to do is to copy a new WAR replacing the old file. Tomcat will discover modified file and redpeloy (stop old and start new one) the application without server restart. This is called hot-deployment

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Yes, I know of this. But I have heard that it slows down the server. Is this not true or significant?

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson: no, it doesn't slow down the server. However it is very easy to introduce Class loader leak which will increase PermGen size during every hot deployment - and eventually cause OOME. But a healthy application should not introduce such leaks (this must be tested).

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Webapps can be arbitrarily restarted: there is no need to restart all webapps to restart one of them, and hot deployment is also not required. Tomcat's manager webapp can be used to deploy, redeploy, or undeploy at will.

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson The Tomcat manager application /can/ be used from the command line. Tomcat's documentation even includes instructions for using the available Apache Ant tasks that can be used to interact with the manager webapp to perform various tasks (e.g. redeploy).

Answer (score 1):

You are right that hosting of multiple we applications on one application server / web container (either Tomcat or other) has benefits.

You mentioned the robustness issue when one application may cause failure of another. But let's simplify this: even if you have only one application you still want 24*7 availability. To achieve this goal people typically run more than one instance of application server with identical application on each one and load balancer in the enterence to the site. The same is relevant for several web applications. Just run N (2 as minimum) application servers with identical set of web applications deployed and load balancer. You will probably need a kind of watchdog that restarts server if it failed or if it stopped responding etc.

In some cases kind of clustering is required. But it is other story.